# On the Mac, using the TV app, how to tell the current resolution the movie is playing at?

Tags: mac, tv.app

**The short question is:** I want to see on my Mac, is the TV app streaming the movie at 4K, or is it 1080p. How is it done?

---

My Internet speed is exactly 25Mbps, which is the Apple TV 4K's streaming requirement. (but it is right at the borderline). I read that at times, it may need up to 35Mbps to be able to stream 4K (probably when it has a lots of action scenes).

So When I am streaming a movie using the TV app on the Mac, is there a way to tell whether it is 1080p or 4K it is streaming at?

With YouTube showing a free video stream, it is possible. With a paid movie on the TV app, is it possible?

This is how it is possible on YouTube by clicking on the Settings icon:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found one way, but it is by "inferring it". It is as follows:

Find a 4K movie, and find a minute of it that has constant actions, just so that it is not "immobile" for the most part. That way, the bitrate demand is high or should be near its max.

Then, bring out the Activity Monitor app, and switch to the Network tab.

Now, watch the movie for 1 minute (for that constant action).

Then, switch over to the Activity Monitor app.  If the Network history was constantly getting 2MB, 3MB per second for most of the time, then it is 4K resolution.  Why?  Because at 2MB, 3MB per second, then in 90 minutes, it is pulling about 13GB. Assuming average is 2.5MB per second:

90 × 60 × 2.5 = 13.5 GB

A 1080p movie is never 13GB. It is merely about 4GB or 5GB. (iTunes used to list movie sizes, and it was typically about 4.5GB for 1080p movies).

So if the Network history was 2MB, 3MB, and then it drops to 0 or very low bitrate like 4kb/s, and for 50% or even 70% of the time, then you know it is 1080p, because it is merely pulling about 4GB for the 90 minutes (vs 13GB).

The drop to 0 or low bitrate for 50% of the time or more means the buffer is full, and the data pulling can "rest" a little bit.